# Restlet CorsFilter with ChallengeAuthenticator

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cors, restlet

I'm building a RESTful API with the Restlet framework and need it to work with cross domain calls (CORS) as well as basic authentication.

At the moment I'm using the [CorsFilter](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/gae/engine/org/restlet/engine/application/CorsFilter.html) which does the job of making my webservice support CORS requests. But, when I try to use this with a simple ChallengeAuthenticator with HTTP Basic Authentication it won't work as I want it to (from a web site).

When I access the webservice directly via Chrome it works as intended, but when I try it in a small web application written in angularjs (jquery/javascript) and try to access the webservice it does not.

Basically what happens is that when a OPTIONS request is sent to my webservice it will not respond with the headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', etc. as it should. Instead it is sending a respond with HTTP status code 401 saying that the authentication failed.. Is this because the authenticator is overriding the CorsFilter somehow?

My *createInboundRoot* method can be seen below.

```
@Override
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            ChallengeAuthenticator authenticator = createAuthenticator();
            RoleAuthorizer authorizer = createRoleAuthorizer();
            Router router = new Router(getContext());
            router.attach("/items", ItemsServerResource.class);
            router.attach("/items/", ItemsServerResource.class);
            Router baseRouter = new Router(getContext());

            authorizer.setNext(ItemServerResource.class);
            authenticator.setNext(baseRouter);

            baseRouter.attach("/items/{itemID}", authorizer);
            baseRouter.attach("", router);
            // router.attach("/items/{itemID}", ItemServerResource.class);

            CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext());
            corsFilter.setNext(authenticator);
            corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
            corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);
            return corsFilter;
        }
```

(The authorizer and authenticator code is taken from the "official" restlet guide for authorization and authentication)

I've tried alot of changes to my code but none which given me any luck. But I noticed that when setting the argument "optional" in ChallengeAuthenticator to true (which ["Indicates if the authentication success is optional"](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.2/jse/api/org/restlet/security/ChallengeAuthenticator.html#ChallengeAuthenticator(org.restlet.Context,%20boolean,%20org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme,%20java.lang.String))) the CorsFilter does its job, but obviously the ChallengeAuthenticator does not care about authenticating the client and lets anything use the protected resources..

Has anyone had a similar problem? Or have you solved this (CORS + Authentication in Restlet) in any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the error message I see when looking in Chrome (where the Origin is the ip of my web server hosting the web application):
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it's a bug of the Restlet CORS filter. As a matter of fact, the filter uses the method `afterHandle` to set the CORS headers. See the source code: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/4e8f0414b4f5ea733fcc30dd19944fd1e104bf74/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/application/CorsFilter.java#L119.

This means that the CORS processing is done after executing the whole processing chain (authentication, ...). So if your authentication failed, you will have a status code 401. It's actually the case since CORS preflighted requests don't send authentication hints.

For more details about using CORS with Restlet, you could have a look at this link: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/. This can provide you a workaround until this bug was fixed in Restlet itself.

I opened an issue in Github for your problem: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1019.

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you for your answer! (Unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer tho..) I will have a look at implementing my own custom "CorsFilter" then and see if I can get rid of this bug :)

Comment: Yepp, no problem.. It seems to work like a charm now! Your implementation, from your blog, was exactly what I needed. Thanks again

Comment: Pleased to hear that it solved your issue. I contacted the person who contributed the cors filter to find a solution to the problem. Stay tuned ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The CorsService (in 2.3.1 coming tomorrow) contains also a skippingResourceForCorsOptions property, that answers directly the Options request without transmitting the request to the underlying filters and server resources.